# Is it OK to use F-words in English culture?

Tags: politeness

Is it OK to use F-words in English culture? I hear my co-workers saying What the fuck or a slang containing "fuck" sometimes. Does it depend on if you are a woman or a man saying it? Or does it depend on if any woman is around? If it is not really inappropriate why don't they say it in front of their kids or on Kids' TV programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by English culture, and whether that means the culture of England or of English speakers. Maybe you could provide more information as to exactly what you mean.

In the USA it is not illegal to say *fuck* in public, unless you are using language that is harassment, 'fighting words', trying to invite violence, etc.  The Supreme Court ruled that the word *fuck* could be displayed on clothing in public property. This is true even in areas where children might see it. Once you take your child out of your home, you risk exposing them to culture at large.

On private property, corporations usually have codes of behavior and dress that employees are expected to adhere to. But pragmatically, unless one is, again, harassing or inciting, one is usually given the slack to use profanity at the work place, within reason. An employer could certainly insist that his employees not do so.

Children are attuned to what their parents, neighbors, and/or caregivers say, so one should monitor the language used around kids if you don't want the F-word passed onto them. Anyway they will probably hear it from some source other than you, say a neighbor or on YouTube before they are in school anyway. It does seem sensible to acknowledge that some words are usually not appropriate for children to use.

If you do not want to hear the F-word, you should avoid most R-rated movies (in USA), and avoid PG-13 movies if you want to avoid milder words, like damn and hell.

In the USA, these guidelines apply equally to men and women, and I've met many a cursing woman. It does still seem a bit unladylike and unseemly for a woman to habitually use profanity other than mild forms, and anyway [research shows that males curse more](https://www.psychologytoday.com/articles/201507/i-am-man-hear-me-swear).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Well, I am more keen to know about English speaking countries rather than just USA. Actually, I have recently migrated to Australia and the culture and language is a bit confusing since I have never been to an English speaking country before and all the knowledge I have comes from mainly Hollywood movies and Series. It is good to see people answering my questions here.

Comment: G'day mate! Well you shoulda just said. Lovely people, very outdoors oriented and for good reason. The English are always cautious of people with too much sun, and then there is the Aussie accent [**here**](http://www.theage.com.au/comment/the-fourth-r-missing-from-australian-education-20151025-gkhv8k.html) and [**here**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3292648/The-Australian-alphabet-formed-drunken-speech-settlers.html).

Comment: G'day mate! Lol

Comment: From the movie Be Cool: "Did you know unless you're willing to take an R rating you can only say the f-word once? Fuck that!" The movie is rated PG-13.

Answer (score 1):

Using

> F-words

in conversation is usually not a problem, may words begin with **F**

> **forest
>
>   film
>
>   foil
>
>   fan**

However, using

> **the F-word**

is called **swearing** is generally not acceptable in most corporate or social situations, situations where the intent is respect or discretion, and especially around children.

Substitutes which get used are

> **firetruck
>
>   fudgesicle
>
>   freak'in**

Just as there are Seven Deadly Sins, there are Seven Words You Can't Say On TV.
**Bad** language is eloquently explained by [**George Carlin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Carlin) in his famous [**monologue**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyBH5oNQOS0)

Comment: Swearing is completely acceptable around women, at least as much as it is around men. Usually you dont swear around children but its fine around adults. There is no separation between the sexes and such beliefs are long since antiquated. I edited your answer due to this sexist and quite simply wrong assertion.

Comment: @Anton Welcome to ELL. You are entitled to your opinion, but I would say the practice varies depending on region in the US and included it to be more on the conservative side where a language learner could take it as a general guideline

Comment: You are absolutely wrong. This kind of belief still persists in some developing nations but not in a country like the US. Women and Men are considered equals. If you were to say something like that in the US you would be considered a bigot.

Comment: @Anton - The US is a big place. I can't find anything "absolutely wrong" in Peter's answer, or in his comment. Women and men may be considered equals, but there are plenty of American men who would feel less comfortable dropping an F-bomb at a baby shower than in a locker room at halftime, and I don't think there's anything bigoted about recognizing that fact.

Comment: This is a question about politeness, not how comfortable people feel being polite/impolite. The reason you cant see the sexist comment is that I edited it out.

Comment: @Anton - I think your edit constitutes an improvement, but I don't think the answer in its original form was "sexist." (It was perhaps chauvinistic at worst, but I wouldn't even go that far, considering the O.P. specifically asked about that issue in the question. You might think that exhorting my son to not drop F-bombs around women constitutes sexism, but I'd counter by saying I'm simply raising him to be a gentleman. But that would be better debated on [parenting.se].)

Comment: @J.R That is sexism. You are training your son to act differently towards men and women. That is what sexism means. If it is only your son(if you have daughters that is) that you raise as such then you are also acting sexist towards them. You can give it a nice title but it doesn't change the nature of the thing. The OP asked if it depends on whether a woman or man says it and if a woman or man is around, to which the only correct answer is "No it does not depend on either". Sexism doesn't just mean stereotypical classic gender roles, it means different treatment for different genitals

Comment: @Anton - That's your opinion, but I hardly agree that it's "the only correct answer." (But if you feel so strongly about it, maybe you should leave an answer of your own.) Also, [sexism has more than one definition](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sexism); some definitions suggest there's more to being sexist than telling a young lad that he shouldn't punch his girl friends in the arm in the same friendly way he might punch his guy friends. (BTW, his sisters have fought fires, driven ambulances, fixed heavy aircraft, and served as soldiers, so I don't think my "sexist" teachings hurt them any.)